# Flyway Ant build not migrating

Tags: java, eclipse, flyway

I am using the below given xml file to execute flyway as an ant task. I am executing the ant file in eclipse using "Run as ant" option. It shows build successful but flyway migration is not happening.

Could you please check and let me know if i need to make any corrections.

```
<path id="flyway.lib.path">
    <fileset dir="${flyway.lib.dir}" includes="**/*.jar"/>
</path>

<path id="flyway.classpath">
    <fileset dir="${sql.dir.emlogis}" includes="**/*.sql"/>
    <fileset dir="${sql.dir.generator}" includes="**/*.sql"/>
    <fileset dir="${sql.dir.pgf}" includes="**/*.sql"/>
</path>



<target name="init-flyway">
    <taskdef uri="antlib:com.googlecode.flyway.ant"
                resource="com/googlecode/flyway/ant/antlib.xml"
                classpathref="flyway.lib.path"/>
  <property name="flyway.driver" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"/>
  <property name="flyway.url" value="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=ElmGenerator"/>
  <property name="flyway.user" value="sa"/>
  <property name="flyway.password" value="EmLogis123"/>
  <property name="flyway.baseDir" value="${sql.dir.generator}"/>
  <property name="flyway.classpath" value="${sql.dir.generator}"/>
  <property name="flyway.table" value="schema_history"/>
 <property name="flyway.locations" value="${sql.dir.emlogis},${sql.dir.generator}"/>
    <property name="flyway.placeholders.custName" value="Maple"/>
    <property name="flyway.placeholderPrefix" value="$("/>
    <property name="flyway.placeholderSuffix" value=")"/>
    <property name="flyway.outOfOrder" value="false"/>
    <property name="flyway.validateOnMigrate" value="true"/>
    <property name="flyway.cleanOnValidationError" value="false"/>
    <property name="flyway.initOnMigrate" value="false"/>
</target>

<target name="deployDB" depends="init-flyway">
    <flyway:migrate>
        <locations>
            <location path="${sql.dir.emlogis}"/>
            <location path="${sql.dir.generator}"/>
        </locations>
        <placeholders>
            <placeholder name="custName" value="Elm"/>
        </placeholders>
    </flyway:migrate>
</target>
```

Regards,
Kavitha

Comment: Have you tried ant deployDB from the command-line? What is the log output?

Comment: It gives me the following error: Complete build sequence is [init-flyway, deployDB, ]

init-flyway:
parsing buildfile jar:file:/C:/Users/kavitha/Desktop/flyway/lib/flyway-ant-2.0.3.jar!/com/googlecode/flyway/ant/antlib.xml with URI = jar:file:/C:/Users/kavitha/Desktop/flyway/lib/flyway-ant-2.0.3.jar!/com/googlecode/flyway/ant/antlib.xml from a zip file

deployDB:
[antlib:com.googlecode.flyway.ant] Could not load definitions from resource com/googlecode/flyway/ant/antlib.xml. It could not be found.  Ignoring Exception java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file reading resource

Answer (score 0):

2 things:

- Don't set baseDir. It has been superseeded by locations.
- locations are the paths below flyway.classpath

Example:

```
flyway.classpath=/my/dir/**.*.sql
flyway.locations=db
```

then Flyway will look for migrations in /my/dir/db

You have set both classpath and locations to the same value, which is incorrect.